# Histogram to Gaussian distribution on Python

Tags: python, distribution, gaussian

I have this histogram:
[image]

I want to have a resulting plot/waveform as like in the picture below? What code or python process to used. Gaussian Distribution is what I'm thinking to use.
[image]
Here are some of the codes I've been using:

```
def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

mean = np.mean(y)
sigma = np.std(y)
# y is histogram list

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaus, x, y, p0=[1, mean, sigma])
plt.plot(x, y, 'b+:', label='data')
z = gaus(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x, z, 'ro:', label='fit')
plt.show()
```

EDIT / UPDATE:
I have edited the histogram plot so as it does not look continuous. The horizontal data/axis is the bin edges(they are measured voltages, measurement done to greater 5000 times). So the number of counts those voltages being hit is the vertical axis. What i wanted for my resulting plot/waveform would be to have two peaks. 1 peak is the maximum number of count and the 2nd peak is the 2nd number of count. How do i upload a list(.txt) in here so I can give you the whole data measurements?
[image]

Comment: So you want to fit two gaussians to the data?

Comment: I divided the histogram data to two parts... each part I put to the Gaussian equation to get the resulting plot. But what I really wanted to is to show the two peaks in histogram data in a Gaussian distribution manner

Comment: You can't make the data be something it isn't.  With a histogram, what you get is what you get, regardless of what you want it to be.  And speaking of histograms, your plot doesn't look like one to me.  Is the vertical axis supposed to be a count?  If so, the plot shouldn't be continuous.  Histograms reflect counts or proportions by bins, because for continuous ranges the probability of exact duplicates is 0 so the count for any particular value should be 1.

Comment: Yes, the plot is not continuous so I have edited the histogram plot so as not to like it. Please see EDIT / UPDATE

Comment: You want to smoothen the curve, right? Check `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`